# Use bluetooth in Android app coded using python

Tags: android, python, kivy

I know there are various tools for creating android apps using python eg python-for-android, android-scripting-evrironment, SL4A etc.

What I need to know is which of these would be helpful if I need my application to use the Bluetooth module of the device.

Comment: Did you try "import bluetooth"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a BluetoothFacade that has been implemented for the upcoming release 5 of SL4A.

The API reference is located at http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/unofficial_apiref

I don't believe that access to Bluetooth services is (at present) available via Kivy or any Kivy-derived project.

Answer (score 2):

It looks kivy start to provide Bluetooth related function now: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [PyBluez](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) library. You need it compiled for ARM cores to use it on Android, but this has already been done and is available from the PY4A website's [Modules page](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/Modules). You just download it to your device, then install it using your PY4A app's Install Module feature.